# How do I log a message when I run a method in a class?

Tags: ruby, logging, instance-variables, self

I wrote the following code. When I run `Hello.run` I want to log a message, but this does not work.

Why does not this work?

```
class Hello
  def initialize
    @logger = Logger.new STDOUT
  end

  def self.run
    self.new
    @logger.warn 'Hello'
  end
end

Hello.run
```

This is the error message I get when running `Hello.run`

```
NoMethodError: private method `warn' called for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@logger` variable you set in the constructor is an instance variable, and `self.run` is a class method.

Instance variables are not available in class methods, so when you're running `Hello.run`, you won't be able to access the `Hello` class' internal instance variable.

If you want the logger to be class wide, you could define it as a class variable, like so:

```
class Hello
  def initialize
    @@logger ||= Logger.new(STDOUT)
  end

  def self.run
    self.new # I don't get why you just create a new instance and throw it away
    @@logger.warn("Hello")
  end
end
```

I have a longer answer on different variable scopes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523547/rails-and-class-variables/11523632#11523632), if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks, I will read your longer answer too. Seems like I just need a better understanding of Ruby classes, and variable scopes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new object of your class.
When you do this `initialize` will be called.

Otherwise `@logger` won't be initialized.

```
hello = Hello.new
hello.run
```

Comment: Since the `run` method is a class method, your example won't work. `def self.method_name` in ruby is called by `ClassName.method_name`.