# naming methods as variables calling methods Ruby

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

hi i am very much a beginner.

i think i understand how the attr_accessor works (below). and the "setter" is the `name=(name)` method. and i know that that method is equivalent to the assignment: `name = "john"`. because "=" is a method that accepts an argument and assigns that argument to whatever object calls it. (though i don't understand how "name" could be considered an object as it is being assigned to an object)

**so my question is:** how can you assign a variable calling a method as a method name? It feels like I'm missing something..

```
class Person
  def name
    @name
  end

  def name=(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you just asking how to use your `name=` method?

Comment: thank you for the reply. am i right in thinking that name= is actually a variable "name" calling the method "=" with a "string" argument. how is that allowed as a method name itself?

Comment: Err, no, the method itself is called `name=`. This is how Ruby denotes setter methods.

Comment: These might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142193/ruby-difference-between-instance-and-local-variables-in-ruby

Comment: thanks the first link was really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so my question is: how can you assign a variable calling a method as a
>   method name? It feels like I'm missing something..

You don't.  In this code

```
def name=(name)
  @name = name
end
```

`name=` **isn't** a variable `name` calling a method `=`.  The **name** of the method is `name=`.

Edit:

In the above code snippet the `def` paired with a terminating `end` constitutes a method definition.

```
def method_name(param1, param2)
  # method body
end
```

On the same line as `def` there can only be the method name, optional parentheses, and the param list.  By definition having a "variable calling a method" in that line would be illegal.  So in your code `name=` is the method name.

Comment: so why if i write this code " object.name = "tim" would it end up calling that method?

Comment: It's just syntactic sugar.  The space before the equal sign is ignored and the method `name=` is called.

Comment: i understand that. but i still don't get why "name=" would call a method with a name "name=" instead of trying to call the method "=" on name. which wouldn't work because of scope. so why is it when i type object.name.=("tim") is that giving me the result of typing object.name=("tim"). I'm going to try and write it out clearer in another box

Comment: sorry i have tried something else. i see that object.name.=("tim") doesn't work. however 5.+(5) does work. are "=" and "+" not the same in that regard?

Comment: No, in `object.name="time"` note that there isn't a dot between `name` and `=`.  That's because the method is `name=`.  In `5.+(1)`, you are calling the method `+` on `5`, passing the argument `1`.

Comment: so by defining the "setter" method:
*****
def name=(name)
  @name = name
end ********
you are re-defining the method "name=" to assign "@name" instead of "name"?

Comment: It isn't a redefinition since it hasn't been defined before. (You don't have an `attr_accessor` call).  Even if you had an `attr_accessor` and hadn't defined your own `name=` method, the assignment would still be to `@name`, not `name`.

Comment: thank you for your time. last question (i hope - just to confirm). if i just assign a local variable. sound = "bang". is that a main.sound=("bang") method? if so, where is that method being defined? or how is that assignment working?

Comment: Hmm... good question.  I'm not sure if assignment is an implicit method call to the `self` object.  Exactly what the `self` object is depends on the scope.

Comment: After doing some reading I don't think that `=` is a method call.

Comment: ahhhhh. then i still don't know what that little = sign is actually doing

Comment: ive reopened the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934375/how-does-the-assignment-symbol-work-ruby