# how does the assignment symbol work - Ruby

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment, attr-accessor

In Ruby if i just assign a local variable.

```
sound = "bang".
```

is that a `main.sound=("bang")` method? if so, where and how is that method "sound=" being defined? or how is that assignment working? if not, what is actually happening?

i know that for a setter method you would say x.sound=("bang"). and you are calling the method "sound=" on the object "x" with the argument "bang". and you are creating an instance variable "sound".

and i can picture all of that. but not when you assign a variable in the "main" object. as far as i know it isn't an instance variable of the Object class... or is it? I'm so confused.

Comment: This information is not enough to answer your all questions..

Comment: the background is a question i asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932032/naming-methods-as-variables-calling-methods-ruby/20932119#20932119.

Comment: i guess the question is "what is the logic behind the code: sound = "bang"? how is Ruby interpreting that?

Comment: Only `sound = "bang"` is can be explained as `sound` is a local variable or you are calling a setter method called `sound=()`.

Comment: where is that method defined?

Comment: In which class do you mean ?

Comment: one ruby book I'm reading. says that "assignments are just calls to regular methods". in the example i used the method is "sound=". so in which class/object is it being defined? and how is ruby defining it as it obviously not defined until you call it

Comment: The assignment operator = is not a method, however methods can have names ending in =

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most programming languages, Ruby included, assignment is a strange beast.  It is not a method or function, what it does is associate a name (also called an lvalue since it's left of the assignment) with a value.

Ruby adds the ability to define methods with names ending in = that can be invoked using the assignment syntax.

Attribute accessors are just methods that create other methods that fetch and assign member variables of the class.

So basically there are 3 ways you see assignment:

- the primitive = operator
- methods with names ending in =
- methods generated for you by the attribute accessor (these are methods ending in =)

Comment: thanks. i think i am beginning to sort of understand what it was that i didn't understand to begin with :p

Answer (score 1):

A variable assignment is just creating a reference to an object, like naming a dog "Spot". The "=" is not calling any method whatsoever.

As @ZachSmith comments, a simple expression such as `sound` could refer to a local variable named "sound"or a method of `self`named "sound". To resolve this ambiguity, Ruby treats an identifier as a local variable if it has "seen" a previous assignment to the variable.

Comment: one ruby book I'm reading. says that "assignments are just calls to regular methods". in the example i used the method is "sound=". so in which class/object is it being defined? and how is ruby defining it as it obviously not defined until you call it

Comment: @Zach Smith: The Ruby interpreter is making some decisions about whether a name assignment in the code is a method or local variable, and treats it differently.

Answer (score 0):

> is that a main.sound=("bang") method?

No. `main.sound="bang"` should set instance variable or element of that variable.
With dot(`main.sound`) you tell object to do some method(in this case `sound`).

To manage local variables ruby create new scope.

```
class E
  a = 42

  def give_a
    puts a
  end

  def self.give_a
    puts a
  end
  binding 
end
bin_e = _ # on pry
E.give_a     # error
E.new.give_a # error
```

Both methods doesn't know about `a`. After you create your class, `a` will soon disappear, deleted by garbage collector. However you can get that value using `binding` method. It save local scope to some place and you can assign it to the variable.

```
bin.eval "a" # 42
```

`lambda`s have scope where they were defined:

```
local_var_a = 42
lamb = ->{puts local_var_a} 
lamb.call() # 42
```